# ef core + automapper + dto: reversemap many to many

Tags: c#, many-to-many, automapper, entity-framework-core, dto

I have problems with a reverse mapping of a many to many relationship. I always get the error "The instance of entity type 'ABXrefModel' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value is already being tracked"

my models:

```
public partial class AModel
{
    public AModel()
    {
        ABXref = new HashSet<ABXrefModel>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ABXrefModel> ABXref { get; set; }
}


public partial class BModel
{
    public BModel()
    {
        ABXref = new HashSet<ABXrefModel>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ABXrefModel> ABXref { get; set; }
}


public partial class ABXrefModel
{
    public int AId { get; set; }
    public int BId { get; set; }

    public BModel B { get; set; }
    public AModel A { get; set; }
}
```

my dto's:

```
public class ADto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<BDto> Bn { get; set; }
}


public class BDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}


public class ABXrefDto
{
    public int AId { get; set; }
    public int BId { get; set; }
}
```

and my mapping Profile:

```
CreateMap<AModel, ADto>()
    .ForMember(dto => dto.Bn, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.ABXref.Select(y => y.B).ToList()))
    .ReverseMap()
    .ForMember(x => x.ABXref, opt => opt.MapFrom(dto => dto.Bn.Select(y => new ABXrefDto{BId = y.Id, AId = dto.Id})))
```

lets say AModel has a ABXrefModel with AId = 1, BId = 1 and I want to update the model from the dto with AId = 1, BId = 1 and AId = 1, BId = 2 I get the previous error. After mapping the collection only has the two values but ef core does not know that one of them is an existing one. But I need to always pass all Bn to ADto, because missing ones have to be deleted. How can I solve this problem. Do I have to modify my mapping or the update of ef core?

Comment: Try AutoMapper.Collection.

Comment: I did try it with the following config

cfg.AddCollectionMappers() with the same result

Comment: Show code used for update.

Comment: update code is very simple _dbSet.Update(model);

             _dbContext.SaveChanges();